# Is there a way to control the bit length of numbers in python?

Tags: python-3.x, bit-manipulation, bit

i have a number such as 0b11001100, which is 8-bits long. i want to always be 8-bit, no more, no less.

what i would like is something either built into python, a module in the standard library, or a module that would be easily portable (if possible).

Comment: "i want to always be 8-bit, no more, no less" → So do you want it in the range `2**7` to `2**8-1`? How do you define overflows? With an  exception?

Comment: 0b11001100 will always be 8 bits long. Are you trying to do fixed-width integer arithmetic? NumPy has data types that would help.

Comment: you can always forced it by discarding extra bits with `n & 0xff`

Comment: @user2357112  For CPython, 0b11001100 is stored internally with 15 or 30 bits, with 0 bits added.  This is all implementation dependent.  vagamens: It is a mystery what you are trying to do.  You need to give some examples of what operations you want to do and what you want the results to be.  You might find the struct module helpful.